# Google Bussiness Messaging OAuth incorrect scope

Tags: web, google-api, google-oauth, backend, google-business

I want my backend through OAuth to gain access to the Google My Business API of clients (other businesses) who have set up business messaging. The idea is for my backend to reply to business messaging, and when the user sends a message, my backend should mark the message as read. The marking of a message as read is documented here - https://developers.google.com/business-communications/business-messages/guides/how-to/message/receipts#receipts_from_agents

When I looked through the documentation, I saw that there is a scope - `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/businessmessages`

(https://developers.google.com/business-communications/business-messages/guides/how-to/integrate/oauth#send_the_authentication_request_suggestion)

But when I try to add it to the OAuth consent settings, I get that it's invalid.

At this stage, I have these scopes in my OAuth access token:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/businesscommunications
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage
```

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
                "domain": "googleapis.com",
                "metadata": {
                    "method": "google.communications.businessmessages.v1.BusinessMessagesService.UpdateReceipt",
                    "service": "businessmessages.googleapis.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Consent screen image:
[image]

The code for generating the OAuth Consent Screen URL:

```js
const { google } = require("googleapis");

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  "clientId",
  "clientSecret,
  "http://127.0.0.1"
);

const scopes = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/businesscommunications",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/businessmessages",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
];

const authorizationUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
  access_type: "offline",
  scope: scopes,
  include_granted_scopes: true,
});
```

You can see that in the `scopes` array the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/businessmessages` is not included because the generated url returns an error for invalid scope

The code for marking a message as read:

```js
async function initAuth() {
    const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
        "clientId", // data from our GCP, not the client's 
        "clientSecret", // data from our GCP, not the client's 
        "http://127.0.0.1" 
        );

    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
        access_token: 'token', // token obtained from the consent screen
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/businessmessages',
    });

    return oauth2Client;
}

async function sendReadReceipt(conversationId, messageId) {
    const auth = await initAuth();

  let apiParams = {
    auth: auth,
    name: 'conversations/' + conversationId + '/messages/' + messageId + '/receipt',
    resource: {
      receiptType:'READ'
    }
  };

  bmApi.conversations.messages.updateReceipt(apiParams,
    {auth: auth}, (err, response) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

Comment: please include [example]

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo done

Answer (score 0):

All the documentation you have linked to (for example: [1]) points to that scope being only used for service accounts. The user authentication component does not require using that scope.

[1] https://developers.google.com/business-communications/business-messages/guides/how-to/integrate/oauth#send_the_authentication_request_suggestion

Comment: I have tried without this scope and only an access token, but again the response from the API is: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes"